# How to extract part of linq to ef to external method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-expressions

I have the following problem. I have a class which is instantiated with LINQ to EF query. Class has a tricky field of type string on which there is some filtering and sorting performed. The tricky field works like this:

```
var result = _context.MyTable.Select(x=> new Model
{
    ...some not interesting properties
    Number =
        x.Id == 0 || !x.Created.HasValue ? null : SqlFunctions.DateName("year", x.Created) +
                                                            SqlFunctions.Replicate("-", 2 - SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.Created.Value.Month).TrimStart().Length) +
                                                            SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 2 - SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.Created.Value.Month).TrimStart().Length) +
                                                            SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.Created.Value.Month).TrimStart() +
                                                            SqlFunctions.Replicate("-", 2 - SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.Created.Value.Month).TrimStart().Length) +
                                                            SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 2 - SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", x.Created).Trim().Length) +
                                                            SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", x.Created).Trim()
    ...more boring properties
});
```

Now, the question is - how to extract at least this awkward part which converts nullable date to "yyyy-MM-dd" string. It would be cool if I could call it like this:

```
var result = _context.MyTable.Select(x=> new Model
{
    ...some not interesting properties
    Number =
        x.Id == 0 || !x.Created.HasValue ? null : MyCustomConvert(x.Created)
    ...more boring properties
});
```

This has to be done with some method returning an expression, but I have too little experience in creating expressions to do this. Any help?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me

Comment: The piece of code I pasted works, but it is very ugly. Also I cannot reuse the conversion logic in other places. Extracting this to an external method returning string like ConvertDateToString will not work, because you'll get exception :

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ConvertDateToString will be raised.

It is however possible, if the method returns Expression<string> and not string - but this I cannot do by myself

Comment: Oh, LINQ to Entities only supports methods written in their homemade classes.

Comment: You can use a get/set method in the class to handle special cases like null DattaTime.  See : https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-properties-get-set

Comment: Are you sure? Will then be filtering and sorting possible on database level? I am querying the table with hundred thousands of records. And what is more important - the problems is not in "nullable" but in the conversion to "yyyy-MM-dd" string

Comment: @jdweng I've checked this - it won't work. I've introduced a property Number like this:         
public string Number => Id == 0 || !Created.HasValue ? null : string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}-{1:00#}", Created, Id);

but the exception is thrown:

The specified type member 'Number' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: I said to use get/set as in the link.

Comment: I don't understand you. Changing expression bodied property to normal getter of course will not change anything. Maybe you think about setting some backing field with a setter - but I don't know how you want to achieve this, since two different values need to be taken under consideration to compute the result string.

Comment: It's possible to do what you are asking with custom expression visitor, but if you don't have experience with expressions, you'd probably better look at some 3rd party library, like the popular LINQKit, or [NeinLINQ](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq/) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out. Huge credit goes to Ivan Stoyev. It turned out to be very easy with NeinLINQ.

The code now can look like this:

```
    public static class LinqToExtensions
    {
            [InjectLambda]
            public static string ConvertToString(this DateTime v) => 
                SqlFunctions.DateName("year", v) + "-" +
                SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 2 - SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)v.Month).TrimStart().Length) +
                SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)v.Month).TrimStart() + "-" +
                SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 2 - SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", v).Trim().Length) +
                SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", v).Trim();

            public static Expression<Func<DateTime, string>> ConvertToString() => v =>
                SqlFunctions.DateName("year", v) + "-" +
                SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 2 - SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)v.Month).TrimStart().Length) +
                SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)v.Month).TrimStart() + "-" +
                SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 2 - SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", v).Trim().Length) +
                SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", v).Trim();
    }
```

And now my code can be rewriten as:

```
    var result = _context.MyTable.ToInjectable().Select(x=> new Model
    {
    ...some not interesting properties
        Number = x.Id == 0 || !x.Created.HasValue 
            ? null 
            : x.Created.Value.ConvertToString()
        ...more boring properties
    });
```

And it can be simplified even more...